# AdListner not working properly

Tags: android, admob

I wish to remove the ad if they are clicked once.
I implemented the following code.
I also added `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`
in the manifest and `android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"` in the activity section of the manifest.

But when i click on the ad and return to the app the ad is still showing .
My code is as follows.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdListener{
 adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.ad);

       adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
 // my code

  @Override
public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
    if (adView != null) {
        adView.destroy();
      }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



@Override
public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



@Override
public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



@Override
public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



@Override
public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
adView.setAdListener(this); /* first you should add listener register */

and for dismiss screen


public void onDismissScreen(Ad p1)
{
    yourlayout.removeView(adView); // your layout should me remove here
}
```

Comment: what to write in the  `yourlayout`..  i have the adview in a relative layout 
    
        `<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        >

     <com.google.ads.AdView

         xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib    /com.google.ads"

        android:id="@+id/ad"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

         ads:adUnitId="my id"
         ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
       
      />
     </RelativeLayout>`

Comment: your contentview in which you are show your adview show means(main layout in technicle world)

Comment: altaf can you have a loke at this please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674643/admob-adlistner-not-working-properly